# Ошибка захвата кадра при улучшенном рендеринге

Tags: opengl, matlab

Коротко о главном:
Имеется фигура, в которой осуществляют движение объекты. Для того, чтобы запечатлеть это движение я использую буфферную матрицу, которая содержит снимки, полученные через getframe(fig), добавляемые вдоль четвертого измерения через cat (поскольку снимки трехмерные).
После окончания цикла буфферная матрица считывается и экспортируемы рисунки помещаются в папку через imwrite. Все гут и работает, однако стоит только подключить openGL рендер:

```
set(fig,'renderer','opengl')
```

как матрица начинает наполняться одинаковыми снимками. Drawnow ситуацию не спасает. Если использовать не openGL, а zbuffer, все снова работает, да вот только zbuffer не ускоряет процесс совершенно.
Как заставить адекватно работать захват кадра при openGL?

Comment: Так, решение нашло само себя - установил 2014 версию матлаба и все встало на место. Ошибка была в 2008. Промежуточные версии не пробовал)